# Como faço para exibir uma movimentação do banco de dados do Firebase?

Tags: banco-de-dados, firebase

Estou com problema em recuperar o conteúdo de movimentação que está armazenado no Firebase, que tem por sua vez o usuário `dHJldml6YW5AZ21haWwuY29t` e email, e dentro do email está organizado por data da movimentação, por exemplo `122018`, então, gostaria de listar esse movimento. Já configurei o calendário, só que não aparece nada no meu `Movimentacao.class`, que é onde deveria aparecer.

[image: Meu Firebase]

Fiz assim:

```
private FirebaseAuth autenticacao = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseAutenticacao();
private DatabaseReference firebaseRef = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseDatabase();
private DatabaseReference usuarioRef;
private ValueEventListener valueEventListenerUsuario;
private ValueEventListener valueEventListenerMovimentacoes;

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private AdapterMovimentacao adapterMovimentacao;
private List<Movimentacao> movimentacoes = new ArrayList<>();
private DatabaseReference movimentacaoRef;
private String mesAnoSelecionado;
```

**Método para recuperar movimentações, que não funcionou!**

```
//Recuperar Moviventações
public void recuperarMovimentacoes(){

    String emailUsuario = autenticacao.getCurrentUser().getEmail();  //recupera o email do usuário logado da base de dados do Firebase
    String idUsuario = Base64Custom.codificarBase64(emailUsuario);  //recupera o email do usuário por meio da Base64 codificando-o

    movimentacaoRef = firebaseRef
            .child("movimentacao")
            .child(idUsuario)
            .child(mesAnoSelecionado);


    valueEventListenerMovimentacoes = movimentacaoRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            movimentacoes.clear();

            for (DataSnapshot dados: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                Movimentacao movimentacao = dados.getValue(Movimentacao.class);

                Log.i("dadosRetorno", "dados: " + movimentacao.getCategoria());
                movimentacoes.add(movimentacao);

            }
            adapterMovimentacao.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Este é meu código `Movimentacao.java`:

```
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;

import br.com.software.trevizan.organizesuascontas.config.ConfiguracaoFirebase;
import br.com.software.trevizan.organizesuascontas.helper.Base64Custom;
import br.com.software.trevizan.organizesuascontas.helper.DateCustom;

public class Movimentacao {

    private String data;
    private String categoria;
    private String descricao;
    private String tipo;
    private Double valor;

    public Movimentacao() {
    }

    public void salvar(String dataEscolhida){

        //Recupera o email do usuário e codifica para base64
        FirebaseAuth autenticacao = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseAutenticacao();
        String idUsuario = Base64Custom.codificarBase64(autenticacao.getCurrentUser().getEmail());

        //Recupera a data, isto é, o mês e o ano que foi configurado dentro do DateCustom.java na forma que foi configurado lá
        String mesAno = DateCustom.mesAnoDataEscolhida(dataEscolhida);

        DatabaseReference firebase = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseDatabase();
        firebase.child("movimentacao")
                .child(idUsuario)
                .child("email")
                .child(mesAno)
                .push() //cria o Id único do firebase na base de dados
                .setValue(this);
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getCategoria() {
        return categoria;
    }

    public void setCategoria(String categoria) {
        this.categoria = categoria;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    public String getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public void setTipo(String tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    public Double getValor() {
        return valor;
    }

    public void setValor(Double valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }
}
```

Este é meu `AdapterMovimentacao.java`:

```
public class AdapterMovimentacao extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterMovimentacao.MyViewHolder> {

List<Movimentacao> movimentacoes;
Context context;

public AdapterMovimentacao(List<Movimentacao> movimentacoes, Context context) {
    this.movimentacoes = movimentacoes;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemLista = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_movimentacao, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(itemLista);
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Movimentacao movimentacao = movimentacoes.get(position);

    holder.titulo.setText(movimentacao.getDescricao());
    holder.valor.setText(String.valueOf(movimentacao.getValor()));
    holder.categoria.setText(movimentacao.getCategoria());

    if (movimentacao.getTipo().equals("d")) {
        holder.valor.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
        holder.valor.setText("-" + movimentacao.getValor());
    }
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return movimentacoes.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView titulo, valor, categoria;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        titulo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textAdapterTitulo);
        valor = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textAdapterValor);
        categoria = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textAdapterCategoria);
    }

}

}
```

Isso tudo será exibido no `Movimentacao.class`.

O que tá dando erro? O Log `Log.i("dadosRetorno", "dados: " + movimentacao.getCategoria());` não mostra nada!

Comment: Amigos, alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Note que na arvore tem um nó "email" entre o "dHJldml6YW5AZ21haWwuY29t" e "122018"

Na hora se salvar vc pode tirar este nó quando buscar incluir como no exemplo abaixo

movimentacaoRef = firebaseRef
            .child("movimentacao")
            .child(idUsuario)
            .child("email")
            .child(mesAnoSelecionado);